# Apply a filter on a column to delete rows

Tags: r

I am new to R I have a simple question on deleting if a condition is not met.

I have a CSV file, one column is IP Address, issue not all are IP Address do want to delete rows that are not IP Address.

Sample table `My.Data`

```
ID.         SIP           DIP
1.      123.243.0.1       56
2.      123.143.0.1       89
3.      0.16783633        44
4.      123.143.0.1       89
```

So want to delete any thing in `My.Data$SIP` that no `[O-9]{3}\.[O-9]{3}\.[O-9]{3}\.`

I am lost and I am using `dplyr`

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` with `grepl`. I'm assuming here that the patter for an IP address is "digits plus dot 3 times, then digits".

```
library(dplyr)
My.Data %>%>
  filter(grepl("^(\\d+\\.){3}\\d+$", SIP))
```

Comment: Your regex isn't quite correct as you need to limit the digits to 1 to 3 digits, your regex would not filter out "1234.5.6.7".  I believe something like `"^(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d+$"` would work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already familiar with regular expressions so you can do something like:

```
hits = grepl(pattern = "[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}", x = My.Data$SIP)
My.Data2 <- My.Data[hits,]
```

Basically this just makes a logical vector of whether or not that column of your data frame matches the regular expression. We then subset the data based on that vector.

Comment: Hello, I ran what you provide and got a the following          [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE , This is heading right direction missing something I am using R Studio Version 1.0.136 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc. , Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: `My.Data = data.frame(SIP = c("023.152.342", "not close", "21.425.321")) grepl(pattern = "[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}", x = My.Data$SIP)`? I'm guessing that you're not feeding it the right vector for x or something else small.